# Read xml file and how to modify logical operations using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, array-indexing

```xml
$xml = [xml] @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>
    <product description="phone" id="1234/5678">
        <item name="apple" version="50" />
        <item name="banana" version="100" />
    </product>
    <product description="notebook" id="6666/7777">
        <item name="orange" version="150" />
    </product>
</group>
'@
```

`$xml.group.product[0].item[0].name` works (returns `'apple'`), because the 1st `product` element has *2* `item` child elements.

However, `$xml.group.product[1].item[0].name` does *not* work (returns `$null`), because there is only *one* `item` element.

How can I reliably access the first `item` child element without having to know whether it happens to be the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example xml isn't quite valid, so I'm going to use a slightly modified version:

```
$xml = [xml] @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>
  <product description="phone" id="1234/5678">
    <item name="apple" version="50" />
    <item name="banana" version="100" />
  </product>
  <product description="notebook" id="6666/7777">
    <item name="orange" version="150" />
  </product>
</group>
"@
```

In your scenario, there's a PowerShell feature called [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) which applies to your first `product` node and returns an **array** of all the child `item` nodes, but for the second `product` node it just returns the `item` node itself:

```
PS> $xml.group.product[0].item.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]

PS> $xml.group.product[1].item.GetType().FullName
System.Xml.XmlElement
```

As a result you can index into the array from the first `product` node, but not the XmlElement from the second, which gives the behaviour you've seen.

To fix this, what you could do is coerce the `item` nodes into an array so that you can index into it even if there's only one `item`:

```
PS> @($xml.group.product[0].item).GetType().FullName
System.Object[]

PS> @($xml.group.product[1].item).GetType().FullName
System.Object[]

PS> @($xml.group.product[1].item)[0].name
orange
```

Comment: +1 for the right explanation and effective workaround, but that there shouldn't be a need for `@(...)`, because PowerShell generally allows indexing even into scalars (e.g., `(42[0])`), in an effort to unify handling of scalars and collections.
There is currently a conflict with the type-native `XmlElement` indexer, which accepts _strings_ to access _child elements_, but I think this conflict can and should be resolved so
that _numeric_ indexing works consistently. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11189).

Comment: @mklment0 - I've updated the examples to remove ```write-host```. I normally avoid the output stream and litter my code with ```write-host``` and ```return ``` instead to make it clear what's going on - too many late nights trying to find where a value is being unexpectedly output from a function which is calling something like ```StringBuilder.Append``` to remember :-).

Comment: I appreciate the update, @mclayton. If you _know_ the true purpose of `Write-Host` and when its use is appropriate, it's obviously fine to use it, but it's better not to make that assumption on SO, especially for newcomers familiar with shells that require something like `echo` to print to the console _and_ output data; they often - understandably, but incorrectly - think that `Write-Host` is the PowerShell equivalent.